# hibernate class is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

help me with my problem..
When i use method `getDriversByBus(Bus bus)`, i have a problem with mapping.

Model:
Bus
bus_id pk
number

Driver 
driver_id pk
name

busdriver
bus_id fk
driver_id fk

Bus

```
public class Bus {
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    private Set drivers = new HashSet();

    public Bus(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Set getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }

    public void setDrivers(Set drivers) {
        this.drivers = drivers;
    }



}
```

Driver

```
public class Driver {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set busses = new HashSet();

    public Driver(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set getBusses() {
        return busses;
    }

    public void setBusses(Set busses) {
        this.busses = busses;
    }


}
```

1 class - Driver:

```
public class DriverDAOImpl implements DriverDAO{

@Override
public void addDriver(Driver driver) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(driver);
        session.getTransaction().commit();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка при вставке", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }

}

@Override
public Collection getAllDrivers() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Collection getDriversByBus(Bus bus) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = null;
    List drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Long bus_id = bus.getId();

        Query query = session.createQuery("select d"+
                " from com.ee.model.Driver d JOIN d.busses bus"
                + " where bus.id =:busid ").setLong("busid", bus_id);




        drivers = (List<Driver>)query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally{
        if(session!=null && session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return drivers;
}
}
```

2 Class - Bus
    public class BusDAOImpl implements BusDAO {

```
@Override
public void addBus(Bus bus) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Session session = null;
        try {
          session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
          session.save(bus);
          session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка при вставке", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } finally {
          if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {

            session.close();
          }
        }
      }


@Override
public Collection getAllBusses() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Session session = null;
        List busses = new ArrayList<Bus>();
        try {
          session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
          busses = session.createCriteria(Bus.class).list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка 'getAll'", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } finally {
          if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
          }
        }
        return busses;
      }


@Override
public Collection getDriverByBus(Driver driver) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = null;
    List busses = new ArrayList<Bus>();
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Long driver_id = driver.getId();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select b "+ 
        "from Bus b INNER JOIN b.drivers driver"+
                " where driver.id =:driverid ").setLong("driverid", driver_id);
        busses = (List<Bus>)query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally{
        if(session!=null && session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return busses;
}

}
```

My mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22.02.2013 19:34:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ee.model.Bus" table="busses">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="bus_id" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="number" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMBER" />
        </property>
        <set name="drivers" table="busdriver" inverse="false" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="bus_id" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many column="driver_id" class="com.ee.model.Driver"></many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 22.02.2013 19:34:20 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ee.model.Driver" table="drivers">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="driver_id" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="busses" table="busdriver" inverse="false" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="driver_id" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many column="bus_id" class="com.ee.model.Bus"></many-to-many>

        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

MainClass:

```
public class EEMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    Collection busses = Factory.getInstance().getBusDAO().getAllBusses();
    Iterator iter = busses.iterator();
    System.out.println("All busses");
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Bus bus = (Bus) iter.next();
        Collection drivers = Factory.getInstance().getDriverDAO().getDriversByBus(bus);
        Iterator itr2 = drivers.iterator();
        System.out.println("Bus # " + bus.getNumber());
        while (itr2.hasNext()){
            Driver driver =  (Driver) itr2.next();
            System.out.println("Name: "+ driver.getName());
        }
    }



}
```

}

hibernate.cfg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="ee">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="com/ee/model/Driver.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/ee/model/Bus.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
     </hibernate-configuration>
```

Factory

```
public class Factory {
    private static BusDAO busDAO = null;
    private static DriverDAO driverDAO = null;
    private static Factory instance = null;

     public static synchronized Factory getInstance(){
            if (instance == null){
              instance = new Factory();
            }
            return instance;
          }


      public BusDAO getBusDAO(){
        if (busDAO == null){
          busDAO = new BusDAOImpl();
        }
        return busDAO;
      }

      public DriverDAO getDriverDAO(){
        if (driverDAO == null){
          driverDAO = new DriverDAOImpl();
        }
        return driverDAO;
      }

}
```

HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
      private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        static {
          try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

Error text:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select this_.bus_id as bus1_2_0_, this_.NUMBER as NUMBER2_0_ from busses this_
Hibernate: select drivers0_.bus_id as bus2_2_1_, drivers0_.driver_id as driver1_1_1_, driver1_.driver_id as driver1_0_0_, driver1_.NAME as NAME0_0_ from busdriver drivers0_ inner join drivers driver1_ on drivers0_.driver_id=driver1_.driver_id where drivers0_.bus_id=?
Hibernate: select busses0_.driver_id as driver1_0_1_, busses0_.bus_id as bus2_1_1_, bus1_.bus_id as bus1_2_0_, bus1_.NUMBER as NUMBER2_0_ from busdriver busses0_ inner join busses bus1_ on busses0_.bus_id=bus1_.bus_id where busses0_.driver_id=?
All busses
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: drivers is not mapped [select d from drivers d , busses b where d.id = b.id and b.id =: busid]
Bus # 10
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3291)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
    at com.ee.DAO.DriverDAOImpl.getDriversByBus(DriverDAOImpl.java:59)
    at com.ee.EEMain.main(EEMain.java:36)
```

Comment: why do you have piece of java code in your mapping? is it a part of above java program or it is really part of your mapping?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the Driver class/mapping file in the main hibernate config file.

Comment: Where do you build your sessionfactory?

Comment: @user15 okay, i changed it)) but it is not solve

Comment: @bmorris591 OP declares `sessionfactory` in the static block in HibernateUtil.

Comment: Why does anyone still use hbm files when annotations have been around for about 10 years!?

Comment: @JBNizet no, I have not forgotten

Comment: The exception talks about a class named `com.ee.mode.Driver`, whereas your mapping talks about a class named `com.ee.model.Driver`. Clean up your sources.

Comment: @JBNizet it's not helped

Comment: Strange Stacktrace shows that com.ee.Driver class is not mapped. But according to above code hbm is present and mapping found in cfg file.  it is

Comment: @СултанАбубакиров show your Bus and Driver class also show your database schema. p.s. why some of names in your db you set in UPPER case and some in lower case??

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak i add my classes and write about model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to isolate the problem source. Since you are declaring your sets as non lazy. What does it tell you when you try to iterate on bus.getDrivers() Set ?

Comment: why it's not correccted?
i have relation many to many it's mean a create speacial table "busdriver"

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I didn't see the many-to-many relation. Sorry again. I will see it now

Comment: if i change "busdriver" on any name, i had error  "Table 'mydb.busdriver1' doesn't exist"

Comment: I changed my answer. Please try to call bus.getDrivers() and see what happens

Comment: I want you to iterate on that Set or at least in a log info, see if the set is displayed correctly

Comment: add me in skype maly_loox please

Comment: mabe try to change Set busses to Set<Bus> busses and Set drivers to Set<Driver> drivers

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is a mixup between mode.Driver and model.Driver.  The SQL generated from Hibernate and the error message are talking about com.ee.mode.Driver but most of the mappings and code above have com.ee.model.Driver.

I cannot see the error in the code above, and if it was in the java it would probably not compile therefore I suspect that the configuration is picking up an older mapping file than the one in the question above which has since been corrected.

The real problem I think is that Hibernate is looking for a Set named "drivers" in the Bus class.  I don't think the code for the Bus class has been included above, but I think that is at the heart of the problem.  Maybe it has the wrong name or something.  It should look like:

```
public class Bus {
private int id;
// Blah blah
private Set drivers;
// blah 
}
```

Comment: okay, i changed com.ee.model.Driver, but it's not helped to )

Comment: Where did you change this and do you still get the same error or a new error?  I think the file that probably needed changing was the mapping for Bus.

Comment: in source and here..and change here

Comment: i checked addBus, addDriver, getAllBusses, getAllDrivers all methods works. But getDriversByBus(Bus bus) doesn't work..my be need changed query?